# Synaptic package manager question

Tags: package-management, synaptic

Why does the synaptic package manager display results for applications that have already been removed?

Answer (score 1):

Synaptic is not what Windows' **Add/Remove Programs** or **Uninstall a program** control panel is!

It shows you software packages that are available to install and also the packages that are already installed on your system.

If you want to see only what is installed on your system, click the **Status** button and select **Installed**.

[image]